# Spring boot project Horizontal separation coding model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing all spring projects using horizontal style i.e feature after feature into same project. what is the disadvantage  of this style, over vertical style i.e. main project and sub project of repositories, sub project of services,..
Please let me know if i have to follow vertical style for large projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the horizontal approach is when you have several project domains and you split your resources in different teams, for example, UI team, Data team and Business Logic, then the 3 teams work in parallel and should not have to communicate between each other.

The Vertical you only have one team and all resources work in all levels of your project (MVC for example).

Personally If is a new project I would try to use the Vertical option, then all members have similar knowledge and is easier to deal with new member or if some guys leave the team.

Here you can find a nice article with some images to clarify it:

https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/horizontal-vs-vertical-slicing/

http://blogs.adobe.com/agile/2013/09/27/splitting-stories-into-small-vertical-slices/

EDIT: Also would depend on the people in your team, if there are people really specialized in a specific technology as BackEnd/FrontEnd,...probably the most effective is use the Horizontal option

Comment: thanks my perception of H and V was totally different before looking at adobe blog. My perception was left DB/Repositories and right Web/Controller. [services and others in between]. I was using vertical i.e. writing full feature across all layers. The answer was helpful. thanks